# Warning: Undefined property: wpdb::$questions

Tags: php

I have an error that ive been dealing with since forever.. Im making a question viewer in wordpress and it shows this error

*Warning: Undefined property: wpdb::$questions*

This is my code, i dont see whats wrong with it.

```
// Show the open questions
    echo '<div style="overflow-x: auto;">';
            echo "<br>Open Vragen<br>";
            global $wpdb;
            $table_name = "questions";
            $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT `uniq_name`, `short_question` FROM .$table_name. WHERE q.status = 'open' ORDER BY q.id DESC");
                foreach ($myrows as $details) {
echo "<table><TR><TH>Vragen&nbsp;</TH><TH>Beantwoord&nbsp;</TH><TH>Niet Beantwoord&nbsp;</TH></TR>";
                  echo $details->id;
                  echo $details->short_question;} 
            }
```

Comment: `FROM .$table_name. WHERE` That is adding dots `.` at the start and end of the table name, most likely not what you want

Answer (score 0):

calling the var by {$table_name} instead of .$table_name. might help
[php string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple)

Comment: didnt work unfortuantly

Comment: and this is the whole code? the query  "SELECT `uniq_name`, `short_question` FROM questions WHERE q.status = 'open' ORDER BY q.id DESC" returns anything? if not (try $wpdb->last_error)
if your query returns data, the error lies somewhere else